# Bitmap.createBitmap(src, x, y, width, height) not working as expected

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm trying to break a source image into 9 sub images which I will give to 9 ImageViews. Im using `Bitmap.createBitmap(src, x, y, width, height)` but the result is never right. My source is 300x300 and I use the following code to break up the source image into 100x100 images:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            pieces.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(sourcePuzzle, i*100, j*100, 100, 100));
        }
    }
```

pieces is an `ArrayList` of `Bitmaps`. Then I go iterate over pieces and assign each value to a unique `ImageView` using `subImage.setImageBitmap(pieces.get(i));`
and then `imageViews.add(subImage)`. (imageViews is an arraylist of ImageViews).

When they display on screen, the imageViews aren't displaying the portion of the source image as expected. It is always off by some offset and it may even be scaled too. Isn't the origin in the top left? Do I need to account for screen density? (something I know little about)

Comment: Without seeing more i think it's got to do with the sizes and scaling of the imageviews because your code looks ok. By the way, is the source puzzle image same 300x300 in all of them drawables representing it?

Comment: I only have one source image. For some reason Android studio only generated one drawable folder called drawable so I need to figure out how to add the other files for different screen densities. That could be my issue.

Comment: The more i read about the studio, the more i dislike it